# set expiration time for WebView cache in android

Tags: android, kotlin, caching, webview

in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#LOAD_DEFAULT) of **WebView's cachingMode**, in the **LOAD_DEFAULT**'s description says:

*If the navigation type doesn't impose any specific behavior, use cached resources when they are available and **not expired**, otherwise load resources from the network.*

how can I set expiration time for web view's caching in android client without needing to modify server-side configuration?

also I have checked out following useful links: [link1](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/10337690), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860886/how-to-make-webview-refresh-its-cache-automately-when-html-content-has-changed) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404580/android-webview-cache-doesnt-expire).

Answer (score 0):

do that by using WorkManager,
create periodic workmanager to call your 'clearWebViewCache' function (like every day)

Comment: clearCache method clears data for other usages of web view in app.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a custom web view client based on OkHttp?

Try this:
add okhttp client as dependency:

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.1'`

Next create a OkHttp interceptor, In this interceptor you can define your cache age:

```
import okhttp3.CacheControl
import okhttp3.Interceptor
import okhttp3.Response
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit


class CacheInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())

        val cacheControl = CacheControl.Builder()
            .maxAge(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // 1 minute cache
            .build()

        return response.newBuilder()
            .removeHeader("Pragma")
            .removeHeader("Cache-Control")
            .header("Cache-Control", cacheControl.toString())
            .build()
    }
}
```

Implement it:

```
...
lateinit var wb: WebView
    lateinit var okHttpClient: OkHttpClient
    lateinit var cache: Cache
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val httpCacheDirectory = File(applicationContext.cacheDir, "http-cache")
        val cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024 // 10 MiB
        val cache = Cache(httpCacheDirectory, cacheSize.toLong())
        okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(CacheInterceptor())
            .cache(cache)
            .build()
        wb = findViewById(R.id.webView)
        wb.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            //  API 21-
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                url: String
            ): WebResourceResponse? {
                return this.getNewResponse(url)
            }

            //  API 21+
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            override fun shouldInterceptRequest(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest
            ): WebResourceResponse? {
                return getNewResponse(request.url.toString())
            }

            private fun getNewResponse(url: String): WebResourceResponse? {
                return try {
                    val okHttpRequest: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
                    val response: Response = okHttpClient.newCall(okHttpRequest).execute()
                    WebResourceResponse("", "", response.body!!.byteStream())
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    null
                }
            }
        }
    }
...
```